# Huge “apply now” banner at the top of job page is very annoying

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs, user-interface

Is anyone else finds this “apply now” banner at the top of job page very annoying?

Not only it takes 10% vertical space on my MacBook Pro 13", but it appears with slow animation taking my attention from reading job details. Sometimes it can even appear covering currently reading lines.

Seriously, if I wanted to apply for this job, I'll find a button at the top-right or at the bottom of the page. There is no need for this banner!

[image: Apply Now banner]

Comment: I can't see any animation, can you clarify where this is?

Comment: @Pekka웃 - This happens when you scroll down the page of a job.  As you scroll this banner follows you.  I don't find it that annoying but I'm on a regular PC not a macbook pro.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, I hate those too... and I guess the argument could be made that it's not terribly necessary in this context. It's one thing to get the user to make some low-threshold decision like signing up to a newsletter or making a small purchase by making it as super duper easy as possible to take action, lest they lose interest and proceed elsewhere. I'm sure that is backed up by solid data. But if you're going to make a potentially life-changing decision like applying to a job, you're not going to forgo that just because you'd have to scroll back up to find the appropriate button, no?

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Wow that was deep - I think its simply for convenience.  I don't find them too annoying.  There already is an "Apply Now" right after the job description.  I consider myself UI savvy and don't think anyone is stepping outside of the realm..I mean glassdoor does this too.

Comment: @JonH yeah, I guess it's not necessary, but not really *that* big a deal either way.

Comment: We implemented this feature as part of an experiment designed to increase apply clicks. Since the experiment was successful, I've marked this as status-bydesign.

Answer (score -10):

If it really bothers you just install a browser extension that allows modifying html.

Use Chrome (or other) dev tools to find the id of the tag and remove it.

I would encourage you not to block ads on the site in general because it's to our benefit to help a developer oriented job site like this become successful.

Comment: Stack Overflow [doesn't care about ad blockers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/02/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/).

Comment: @zondo that's a selfish perspective.  if you bother to read the article it says "More accurately: we hope that they won’t" [use ad blockers].  I've got 7 downvotes for trying to help a site I like.  That's always nice.